# MySQL server has gone away + Error reading result set's header

Tags: mysql, prestashop-1.7

I have a website based on `Prestashop 1.7.2.4.` When I go to the payment methods or to the shipping page it takes at least 2 minutes to load and then I get these errors:

> Warning alla linea 134 nel file /home/liggia5/public_html/classes/db/DbPDO.php
>   [2] PDO::query(): `MySQL server has gone away`
>
> Warning alla linea 134 nel file /home/liggia5/public_html/classes/db/DbPDO.php
>   [2] PDO::query(): `Error reading result set's header`

It was working fine last week, I don't know what may have caused this. I've already tried to disable some modules but nothing changes. Anyone can help me, please?

P.S. It only happens with these two pages, everything else is ok

here is a screenshot
[image]

Comment: Have you made any changes in the `Indexing`? Or loaded the data recently?

Comment: I don’t know. I don’t know what you mean. Sorry I’m not an  experienced user